# What does $C_p-C_v=R$ mean? What are its applications?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

So my question is: what does $C_p-C_v=R$ actually mean? It's very straightforward to derive. But my issue is, where and what use does this have in real life applications, and why is it important?

All I have found so far is lab experiments showing this, or the wiki entry to the Mayer equation which outlines the math.

Comment: You know it only applies to an ideal gas, right ?

Comment: Yes, I understand that it only applied to ideal. I was just wondering what the importance of this relationship and it ramification in real world applications. As I mentioned in the OP, there not alot of information that I have come across on the whys and how of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

As you know it only applies to an ideal gas.

Regarding its application, in my experience, which is admittedly limited,  I have found it primarily used to simply solutions to thermodynamic problems through substitution for R.

I will reach out to a trusted colleague of mine (Chet Miller) who has considerable practical experience in thermodynamics and see if it goes beyond that.

Hope this helps

Comment: @Chet Miller See above. Can you provide a better answer?

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated.

Comment: I think the OP needs some practice solving some textbook problems, rather than spending his valuable time speculating about this in advance.  He will get the idea pretty fast.